# Azure Devops Unable to create release trigger based on Github tag

Tags: github, azure-devops, tags, release

I want to create a release only when i create a release in github (it gets tagged with release . I tried to include it as part of build branch in the continuous deployment trigger like this

azure-pipelines/refs/tags/r*

refs/tags/r*

refs/tags/*

But the release pipeline doesn't gets triggered at all.

Comment: try using 
trigger:
- '*'
in your .yml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, if I directly set the "build branch filter" in Release Pipeline CD(continuous deployment), the release will not trigger after creating the new tag.

But the Github tag could trigger the Build Pipeline.

You could try the following steps to set the build and release pipeline:

Step1: Create a build Pipeline. The Pipeline needs to contain a **"Publish build artifacts"** task. This task could create an artifact for release.

Then you need to set the “Continuous integration” trigger(`include:refs/tags/*`)

[image: Build trigger]

Here is a Yaml Sample:

```
trigger:
- refs/tags/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Step2: You could set the "continuous deployment trigger"(`include:refs/tags/*`) in Release Pipeline. (Artifacts source type: **Build**)

[image: Release Trigger]

In this case, when you create a new release tag in Github, the tag will trigger the build pipeline. After the build pipeline ends， the release pipeline will be triggered.

Hope this helps.